# simple calculator in lyx

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I'm trying to find a very simple calculator for lyx.
for now, I just want to do something like this:
1+1-50+30*5= \ans
and let lyx to calculate this.
I could not find something to do that, may you know?

Comment: `\usepackage{xfp}` and then `\fpeval{1+1-50+30*5}`.

Comment: LyX has support for using computer algebra systems. See Help > Math, "23 Computer Algebra Systems". I use maxima for this.

Comment: How do you get maxima to work with Lyx? I have it installed on my windows PC, but it doesn't seem to be working when I try to evaluate a simple expression (like 1+1). Is there a setting or something I have to mess with?

Answer (score 4):

As LyX support Sweave documents, with R installed and in the LyX path, you can:

1. <kbd>Documents</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Modules</kbd> > <kbd>Rnw(knitr)</kbd> > <kbd>Add</kbd> > <kbd>Apply</kbd>
2. <kbd>Insert</kbd> > <kbd>Customs Insets</kbd> > <kbd>Chunk</kbd> or <kbd>S/R expression</kbd> (for more simple maths)

[image: mwe]